# Loop causes Firefox to crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, firefox, crash

So it seems like this javascript loop will sometimes cause my Firefox to overload and crash. I just don't understand why.

```
        //prep genresArray
        var genPrint = ""; //variable initialized to avoid "undefined" in print loop
        var GAL = movieListLocal[i].genresArray;
        for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
            genPrint = genPrint+GAL[i].name+", ";
        }
```

genresArray contains a number of genre-objects, each one with a id and a name (such as adventure, horror etc). I simply want to turn into into a continuous string instead.

Comment: What is the `i` outside the loop? Is that from another loop? If so, the nested loop should use `j` or some other variable. Otherwise the outer loop loses its state.

Comment: You are referencing `i` in `movieListLocal[i].genresArray` before it is even declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this loop is nested inside another loop that also uses `i`. For the inner loop, you should use a different variable name, like `j`.

```
    var genPrint = ""; 

    // outer loop counter----v
    var GAL = movieListLocal[i].genresArray;

    // -----v--inner loop counter
    for(var j=0; j<2; i++){
        genPrint = genPrint+GAL[j].name+", ";
    }
```

JS doesn't have block scope when using `var`, so the inner `i` declaration overwrites the outer one.

It will work with the `let` declaration, coming in ECMAScript 6, and currently available in Firefox.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    console.log("foo", i)
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
         console.log("bar", i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Embarrassing that I didn't see that myself. Tunnel-vision I guess.